# Envoy proxy isn't forwarding to listed address?

Tags: docker, envoyproxy, dapr

So I have a dapr service hosted at: 192.168.1.34:50459

I'm trying to have it communicate with my web application using grpc-web. To do so I have an envoy proxy (according to https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web/issues/347).

My envoy.yaml file is as follows:

```
static_resources:
  listeners:
  - name: listener_0
    address:
      socket_address: { address: 0.0.0.0, port_value: 4949 }
    filter_chains:
    - filters:
      - name: envoy.http_connection_manager
        config:
          codec_type: auto
          stat_prefix: ingress_http
          route_config:
            name: local_route
            virtual_hosts:
            - name: local_service
              domains: ["*"]
              routes:
              - match: { prefix: "/" }
                route:
                  cluster: greeter_service
                  max_grpc_timeout: 0s
              cors:
                allow_origin_string_match:
                - prefix: "*"
                allow_methods: GET, PUT, DELETE, POST, OPTIONS
                allow_headers: keep-alive,user-agent,cache-control,content-type,content-transfer-encoding,custom-header-1,x-accept-content-transfer-encoding,x-accept-response-streaming,x-user-agent,x-grpc-web,grpc-timeout
                max_age: "1728000"
                expose_headers: custom-header-1,grpc-status,grpc-message
          http_filters:
          - name: envoy.grpc_web
          - name: envoy.cors
          - name: envoy.router
  clusters:
  - name: greeter_service
    connect_timeout: 0.25s
    type: logical_dns
    http2_protocol_options: {}
    lb_policy: round_robin
    hosts: [{ socket_address: { address: 192.168.1.34, port_value: 50459 }}]
```

It should listen at 0.0.0.0:4949, and forward it to 192.168.1.34:50459

But when I start this proxy with

```
docker run -d -v envoy.yaml:/etc/envoy/envoy.yaml:ro -p 4949:4949 -p 50459:50459 envoyproxy/envoy:v1.15.0
```

It routes it to 0.0.0.0:50459

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iW8yP.png)

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Comment: one quick thing to try would be to change the `type` of the cluster from `logical_dns` to `strict`.  `type: strict`.  This will stop it from doing any DNS resolution and just use the IP address directly.  [more information](https://www.envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/intro/arch_overview/upstream/service_discovery#supported-service-discovery-types)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about envoy but can you configure it to log to mounted path? See if the route is actually configured? Also, I assume you're setting the `--dapr-grpc-port explicitly` in Dapr run command? Have you tried setting it to a diff port in case of collisions?